# npm start not running in docker

Tags: reactjs, docker

I'm facing a weird problem, it might be something careless on my part.

The problem is basically npm start does not run inside when placed inside a conditional.The entire image is built but the development server does not run, and i would have to manually go in to call the npm start command

Here is some code:
My dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.16.2-alpine
# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/frontend
# copy project
COPY . .
RUN npm install
ARG BUILD_ENV
RUN if [ ${BUILD_ENV} = "DEV" ]; then npm start ;else npm run-script build;fi
```

My docker-compose:

```
  frontend:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      args:
        - BUILD_ENV=DEV
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Here is the process of building the frontend in the console:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM node:12.16.2-alpine
12.16.2-alpine: Pulling from library/node
cbdbe7a5bc2a: Pull complete
f98f8aade4b1: Pull complete
6c9c37ffd044: Pull complete
003e8eba0035: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f48e315114006f6d94f7661b317156178fadd5a2b6aab060cb2eb2759fe3a65a
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:12.16.2-alpine
 ---> 4b3c4c2702d2
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/frontend
 ---> Running in 613d1858cc0d
Removing intermediate container 613d1858cc0d
 ---> 35ced0a94455
Step 3/6 : COPY . .
 ---> a52cea5e9862
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 7bd9c256beb7
Removing intermediate container 7bd9c256beb7
 ---> 67d3df6c748e
Step 5/6 : ARG BUILD_ENV
 ---> Running in 7c76343d47bd
Removing intermediate container 7c76343d47bd
 ---> 854912ab1dbc
Step 6/6 : RUN if [ ${BUILD_ENV} = "DEV" ]; then npm start ;else npm run-script build;fi
 ---> Running in 78b1ac12f58d
> react-app-env start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/frontend/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Removing intermediate container 78b1ac12f58d
 ---> 0b14d6339a3f
```

Comment: The `RUN` command is running as part of your image build (why it's exiting is a separate question).  Do you mean this to be the main `CMD` your image runs?  Why wouldn't you want to `RUN` the `build` action as part of your image build?

Answer (score 0):

This will be run when you build the image **not** when you start the container:

```
RUN if [ ${BUILD_ENV} = "DEV" ]; then npm start ;else npm run-script build;fi
```

You have to use `CMD` to execute the entrypoint of the container.
You also have to make sure to copy the build ARG `BUILD_ENV` to an environment variable, as it needs to be available in the container at runtime.
(I had to adjust the command a bit to make it work.)

```
FROM node:12.16.2-alpine
# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/frontend
# copy project
COPY . .
RUN npm install
ARG BUILD_ENV

# Copy build arg to env.
ENV BUILD_ENV=${BUILD_ENV}
# Run npm start in CMD.
CMD if [ $BUILD_ENV = 'DEV' ];then echo DEV ;else echo NOTDEV;fi
```